# Arduino IDE path for VS Code setup

Tags: path, visual-studio-code, arduino

Arduino IDE installed as an App (in Windows 10), so this path ("arduino.path": "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino",) doesn't exist, what is the correct one?

Comment: Is it - C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.19.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt   ?

Answer (score 2):

Install the normal IDE. Not the windows APP neither the WEB.

Then you can use `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino"`

Comment: Is there a particular process to make sure you're installing the full IDE and not the app or web versions?

Comment: It is easier to say: they are just different.

Comment: Use this https://www.arduino.cc/download_handler.php

Comment: All of the information necessary to answer the question should be in the body of the question. You can use the EDIT button to add more information to improve the answer. While simply saying they are different may make sense to you, the more precise and specific information you can place inside the answer, the more likely it is to be a helpful answer to OP and to others who may find this question looking for their own answers.

Comment: I cant edit the comment, thats why I post a new one.

Comment: If you are using the account you wrote the answer with, you can edit the answer. If you, by mistake perhaps, created a duplicate account then you wouldn't be able to edit the posts created with your other account. You can remedy this by reading and following the simple steps listed here: https://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, nice. But a comment cannot be edited after a while. Please try to edit your upper comment and post the results. On the other hand, I don't know what is supposed to happen with this thread, because we are talking about how to use the platform instead of the question the user asked about. Should we remove the comments? should the thread be deleted? should this be ignored?

Comment: You're mistaking me. I did not suggest you edit your comments. I suggested you edit your Answer. There is no time limit on editing your answers. I know this. I've been a member for more than 8 years and can still edit both my answers and questions. The thing at the top of this thread is an answer, and it has an EDIT button below it. You can't edit your comments, but you CAN edit your answers and questions. Please do so. It should not be necessary to read an entire comment thread to read a full answer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issues. The Windows App doesn't seem to work (at least not for me).

Download the [full IDE installer](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/Software) as described below:

[image: screenshot showing the correct file to download]

Install it, then your PATH will be `C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino` and things like the VSCode extension will work. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

i have installed arduino ide from arduino site. after installation i cant see the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino". insted i have i have "C:\Program Files \Arduino".

i added "C:\Program Files \Arduino" path in VScode for arduino.path and i am always having plese specify arduino.path.

please let me know to fix this error.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1169760)